# My Redirection link is not working.(return redirect('/show');)

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-8

```
$user=new User;
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),$user->rules,$customMessage);
    
if($validator->passes())
{
    $user->first_name=$request->get('fname');
    $user->last_name=$request->get('lname');
    $user->gender=$request->get('gender');
    $user->qualification=$request->get('qualification');
        
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/show');
} 
else {
    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);
}
```

web.php Route is:

```
Route::get('/show',[App\Http\Controllers\CrudsController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
return response()
    ->json(['success'=>'Added new records'])
    ->withCallback($request->input('show'));
```